# A generic MessageBox derived from wx.Dialog

Tags: python, dialog, modal-dialog, wxpython, messagebox

As pointed out in some other topics, `wx.MessageDialog` doesn't respond to many API functions, such as an external call from `Destroy()`, etc. So there is a need for building a `wx.GenericMessageBox` derived from `wx.Dialog`.
Here it is :

[image]

```
import  wx

class GenericMessageBox(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, text, title = ''):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, title = title, size = (360,120), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size = (360, 50), pos = (0,0))
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
        label = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, text, pos = (50,20))        
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size = (360, 40), pos = (0, 50))
        btn = wx.Button(panel2, wx.ID_OK, pos = (250,7))
        self.ShowModal()


app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, 0, 'Test')
frame.Show()
GenericMessageBox(frame, 'This is a message box that is derived from wx.Dialog. You can Destroy() it from anywhere in the code.', 'Test')
app.MainLoop()
```

Unlike `wx.lib.agw.genericmessagedialog`, this one's goal is to have the closest look possible to native OS look (here Windows look). [*`genericmessagedialog` has pictures in the buttons, which is not like Windows' native look*]

**How would it be possible to improve this dialog in order that it its size is automatically increased if `StaticText` needs two lines?**

**Moreover the OK button (x,y) positionning is okay and centered on the grey panel on my machine, but would it be the same on other platforms?**

(I think such a snippet could be useful for community.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage the Layout, it is better to use **Sizer** instead of position.

You can have a try with following code:

use self.setMessageLine(Num) to set the output to see the difference.

```
    import wx

    class MyDialog ( wx.Dialog ):

        def __init__( self, parent ):
            wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 300,200 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

            #set the minimum Size of the frame to Fit()
            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 300,-1 ), wx.DefaultSize )

            fgSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer( 2, 1, 0, 0 )
            fgSizer.AddGrowableCol( 0 )
            fgSizer.AddGrowableRow( 0 )
            fgSizer.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
            fgSizer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_ALL )

            self.m_panel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.SIMPLE_BORDER|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
            gSizer = wx.GridSizer( 1, 1, 0, 0 )

            self.m_staticText = wx.StaticText( self.m_panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"test", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText.Wrap( 10 )
            gSizer.Add( self.m_staticText, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5 )


            self.m_panel.SetSizer( gSizer )
            self.m_panel.Layout()
            gSizer.Fit( self.m_panel )
            fgSizer.Add( self.m_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

            m_sdbSizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
            self.m_sdbSizerOK = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_OK )
            m_sdbSizer.AddButton( self.m_sdbSizerOK )
            self.m_sdbSizerCancel = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_CANCEL )
            m_sdbSizer.AddButton( self.m_sdbSizerCancel )
            m_sdbSizer.Realize()

            fgSizer.Add( m_sdbSizer, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
            self.SetSizer( fgSizer )
            self.Layout()
            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
            self.setMessageLine(10)

        def setMessageLine(self, messageLine):
            msg = ""
            for i in range(0, messageLine):
                msg += "Line %d \n" % i

            self.m_staticText.SetLabel(msg)
            self.Fit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        dlg = MyDialog(None)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        app.MainLoop()
        pass
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to set a max width for a `wx.StaticText` so that if auto-splits into a paragraph of several lines of text is too long ?

Comment: @Basj Yes, try **self.m_staticText.Wrap(SIZE)**